# gestate doesn't recognize numeric variable

Tags: r, survival

I have a survival dataset and want to use package `gestate` for analysis.
When I intent to fit model I obtain:

```
fit2 <- fit_tte_data(data=survdata,Time="dias",Event="entrega",censoringOne=F,type="automatic")

Error in Surv(T, E) : Time variable is not numeric
```

But, when I use glimpse to examine my data I obtain:

[image]

So, both variables ar numeric.

I don't understand where it fails.

Comment: I can't replicate this fault. The code works for me with a random sample of doubles for `dias` and a binomial sample for `entrega`. Perhaps you could type `dput(survdata)` into the console and copy / paste the result into your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Allan. After your suggestion and some interaction with James Bell (one of the authors of gestate package), I've found that if I change my tibble to a dataframe by means of `as.dataframe(survdata)` it works.